# Create Terms on taxonomy by text field

Tags: terms

I want to add terms on a my taxonomy dynamically by a text field and button

sample taxonomy:
place_taxonomy
 - island_term

like:

[Textfield] [submit button]

Comment: Is this going to be on the admin page?  Or will this be on the front end?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set the hierarchy to false, like this:

```
register_taxonomy(  
    'internal_name',  
    'object_type',  
        array(  
            'hierarchical' => false
        )  
);
```